# Get the title of link as title of jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I have a link which updates dynamically. 
For example
     `<a href="x.php" title="Mr X">Image</a>`
     `<a href="y.php" title="Mr XY">Image</a>` to
And goes on...
When I click on the link it open the dialog box.
Now I want to have the title of link as title of opening dialog box.
My code for Dialog goes as.

```
$(function(){
    $( "#navigation" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        var m_title = $(this).attr("title");
        $('<div/>', {})
        .attr('title',m_title)
        .load($(this).attr('href')).appendTo('body').dialog({
        title : m_title,
        position: 'top',
        width : 415,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,        
        });
    });
});
```

But I get Title as blank. Need help to know what's wrong

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CmVc6/

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it doesnot seems to work with latest jquery UI 1.10

Comment: Ummmm, yup, it does. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x974x/

Comment: Your fiddle works for static link on page but..I need the one where links are dynamically being fed by ajax. There it is not working

Comment: Ummmmmm, yup it does: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x974x/1/. Do you plan on continuing to tell me I'm wrong? Just curious.

Comment: I didn't mean that. Your code works. I think I have to explain better.

Comment: I didn't mean that. Your code works. I think I have to explain better. I have a page main.php. In that page I have div id=navigation. Now the content in this div is fed from another page called cars_not_drove.php through ajax load. So the user could only see the images of cars with link, which when clicked opens dialog with title as title contained in the link.